# Event button release doesn't work if another event happens

Tags: python, tkinter

The problem occurs when a mouse button is pressed and not released, another click `event` happens which interrupts the current `event`. I will try to show this with the following code example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
l = tk.Label(bg='red', width=30, height=30)
l.pack(fill='both', padx=100, pady=100)

l.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e: print('pressed'))
l.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', lambda e: print('release'))
root.mainloop()
```

To reproduce this error:

1. Click and hold the left mouse button on the red label.
2. Move the cursor to the white space that is on the `root`. The mouse button must remain pressed.
3. Now press and release the other button while still holding the left mouse button.
4. Release the left mouse button on the white space.

Note: In the 4'th step it is important to stay outside the red `label` otherwise everything will work.

So for some reason the `ButtonRelease-1` event will not happen, most likely because another event happened during the hold process, but it is still not clear for me why.

I want to avoid this. Maybe it is possible to block other events during this process or force other events to work together with this event. I tried to use `break`, also tried to use `add='+'` for the bind functions, but none of that works.

Comment: I don't know what solution to propose, but I found a list of all tkinter [events](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/list-of-all-tkinter-events) and, for instance, there is a `"<Leave>"` event which you can bind to the label to detect when the mouse leaves the label. (Presumably this will indicate that you won't receive a release event now).

Comment: @quamrana Hello. I am not sure how this knowledge can help. It just detects that I left the label, but this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I think its because the new event intercepts the old event..?

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria that is what I was thinking. The problem here is that everything will work fine if you don't leave the red label, other events will not interrupt the current one.

Comment: Maybe because then the event can be re-registered back or something. Not sure. Curious about what use case this can achieve when solved

Comment: The release binding fires for me the instant that I press a second mouse button.

Comment: code works correctly on my Linux.

Comment: @furas it is quite possible that it is a Windows-only problem. From what I've seen so far, code written in tkinter may work correctly on Linux/Macos, but not on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it doesn't work on windows because windows can only have 1 "window" (AKA widget) capturing the mouse with [SetCapture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setcapture), when you click outside of there the focus shifts from the label (static window) to the main window (TKWindow) and the OS is going to send the [WM_LBUTTONUP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-lbuttonup) message to the window instead of the label.

to get around that you could have the parent window handle the mouse event instead of the label, and just check that the mouse is within the bounds of the label, or just live with this problem.

**Edit:** another way is to block events from all of the system until this action is done as follows.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
l = tk.Label(bg='red', width=30, height=30)
l.pack(fill='both', padx=100, pady=100)

def down(e):
    print('pressed')
    l.grab_set_global()

def up(e):
    print('release')
    l.grab_release()

l.bind('<Button-1>', down)
l.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', up)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Although I don't like this solution. It will work, but it will really mess up the whole code. I have a complex project and this will destroy the structure I have. But anyway, thanks for an advice.

Comment: Is there a way to simply block all other events while this event is not finished?

Comment: @DanyaK yes, that can happen, i added that to the answer, but the events that do happen while you are blocking all other events may get queued and happen after the grab is released, so be careful, also this is not a very good user experience as people usually move the mouse away from a button to cancel an event.